# Enabling sidebar in my wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Hey guys am coding a wordpress theme from scratch ..I need to enable a side bar on the right side of my theme.

So in my `functions.php` i have enabled some code like

```
function arphabet_widgets_init() {
  register_sidebar( array(
'name' => 'The sidebar',
'id' => 'home_right_1',
'before_widget' => '<div>',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
'after_title' => '</h2>',
  ) );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
```

In my `sidebar.php`

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #secondary -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

In the `style.css`

```
.widget-area {
float:right;
width:330px;
}
```

But when i run the code the sidebar isnt displaying.I just want to display the sidebar on the right side of my theme page.

Thanx in advance

Comment: may be you need to use `dynamic_sidebar('The sidebar');` ?

Comment: @ViPiN see its already in my code ..but didnt worked

Comment: tried `dynamic_sidebar('home_right_1')` ?

Comment: @ViPiN yes i have ..but the problem remains same

Comment: did u change for both `is_active_sidebar` and `dynamic_sidebar` ?

Comment: @ViPiN yes i have .but the problem remains the same

Comment: @ViPiN can ou please help me ,...:(

Comment: [wpbeginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-dynamic-widget-ready-sidebars-in-wordpress/) has a good [tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-dynamic-widget-ready-sidebars-in-wordpress/) about wp sidebars

Comment: @ViPiN actually i have followed this but it isnt working ..i can give me code..will you be able to test it on ur pc

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use Name or ID of dynamic sidebar

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'home_right_1' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'home_right_1' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And use this function

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {

      register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Main sidebar', 'framewrok'),
        'id' => 'home_right_1',
    'description' => __('Default main sidebar.', 'framework'),
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<div class="widget-title"><h2>',
    'after_title' => '</h2></div>'
      ));
}
```

Comment: if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {

      register_sidebar(array(
 'name' => __('Main sidebar', 'framewrok'),
        'id' => 'home_right_1',
 'description' => __('Default main sidebar.', 'framework'),
 'before_widget' => '<div class="widget %2$s">',
 'after_widget' => '</div>',
 'before_title' => '<div class="widget-title"><h2>',
 'after_title' => '</h2></div>'
      )); }